# List view with button json post volley

Tags: android, listview, post, android-volley

```
CustomListAdapter.java

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Patient> patientItems;
private String url = "http://172.30.16.83/test/apps.php";
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Patient> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.patientItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return patientItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return patientItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    CirculaireNetworkImageView thumbNail = (CirculaireNetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Button viewBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn);
    //TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
    // getting movie data for the row
    Patient m = patientItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());
    viewBtn.setTag(position);
    viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    /*
    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));
    */
    return convertView;
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Patient p=patientItems.get(mPosition);
        final String id=p.getTitle();
        final String image=p.getThumbnailUrl();
        Log.d("Title at row" + mPosition, id);

        Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        jsonParams.put("id", id);
        jsonParams.put("image", image);

        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url,

                new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //   Handle Error
                        Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
                return headers;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
    }
}
}
```

I got a problem that i show that in logcat (json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject). I knew that it get the right params but i cannot send them to the db due to this problem. Please give me some helps to solve this. Thank You.

```
 01-13 01:43:06.946 20721-20721/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/LOG: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"g"},{"image":"http:\/\/172.30.16.83\/test\/2.png"},{"id":"xd"},{"image":"http:\/\/172.30.16.83\/test\/2.png"},{"id":"hallo"},{"image":"http:\/\/172.30.16.83\/test\/2.png"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Share your logcat error message .

Comment: Sorry, I solved this problem but I got another problem and i may edit the question. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Change the `JsonObjectRequest` to `JsonArrayRequest` . Because your return json is a Array.

Exmp.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
    ){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I still have a question. There is an error.      `     01-13 04:15:01.004 25408-25408/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/LOG: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of /  `    . It is because there isn't put the jsonparams so where should I put it?